# pandas dataframe bar style based on function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply "[bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.bar.html)" style to column "bbb" (same as column "ccc") while keeping original contents in column "bbb".

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
 'aaa':['first','second','third','forth','fifth'] ,
 'bbb':['1 of 20','34 of 50', '12 of 24','4 of 5','7 of 9'],
 })

def fn1(x):
    p = x.split(" ")
    return (int(p[0]) / int(p[2]))

df['ccc'] = df['bbb'].apply(fn1)
df.style.bar()
```

I could probably use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) with some fancy css attribute. Can this be achieved with passing some kind of "subset" to [bar()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.bar.html)? Any suggestions much aprechiated.